# Request File from server using sockets

Tags: java, android, python, sockets

I am creating a program where an android device requests a file from a Web Server(running python).The server can receive over sockets with no problem the path of the requested file but i dont know how i can make my android device to wait for a responce.

Here is the android code(as a client requesting a file from web server):

```
 try {

        Socket socket = null;
        socket = new Socket("192.168.1.9", 4000);

        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());


        String str = getURL();
        output.writeBytes(str);

        output.close();
        input.close();
        socket.close();

        {
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }


    Log.d("communicationService", "URL transferred with success");
```

And the python script running on Web Server(It can receive thefile path but i have problem sending the file)

```
import socket
import sys

HOST, PORT = '192.168.1.9', 4000
serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
serverSocket.bind((HOST,PORT))
serverSocket.listen(10)

print 'Server is on and listening to %s ... ' % PORT

while True:

clientSocket, clientAddress = serverSocket.accept()
print 'A client was connected.....'
incomingURL = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print incomingURL

clientSocket.close()
```

Any advice and tip would be really helpful...

Comment: Does this absolutely have to be done with sockets?

Comment: No.I chose sockets because i used them for an older java project.If you have to propose a better way it would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i managed to transfer the files in the end(For those that are interested in apps of this kind).What i did was to create another socket and sent a stream back to client.

```
file = open("path_of_file", "rb")

s = socket.socket()
s = connect((addr,port))
l = file.read(1024)
while (l):
  s.send(l) 
  l.f.read(1024)
file.close()
s.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you should be able to get away with [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html)

If you need to get fancier with a full blown webservice, [WSGI](http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is very popular.

On the client side [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library is by far the easiest way that I've found to make http requests in python. *(just had to plug that one because it's that good)*

Comment: Thx for the reply,i will check it.